# java how to prevent class from being derived more than two levels?

Tags: java, inheritance

In java I need to prevent Level1 class (look at following sample code) from being derived for more than two levels. Deriving till Level2 and Level3 is fine but if class is derived by Level4 then exception should be thrown. Look at following code sample.

Code sample:

```
class Level1 {
    private int level = 1;

    protected Level1() throws RuntimeException {
        level++;
        //System.out.println(level);
        if (level > 2) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Can't implement more than 2 levels");
        }
    }
}

class Level2 extends Level1 {
    protected Level2() {
    }
}

class Level3 extends Level2 {
    Level3() {
    }
}

class Level4 extends Level3 {
    Level4() {
    }
}
```

From above code sample I am not proposing solution using static int level counter. I am just trying to explain the issue.

Is it possible in Java by implementing some logic or by using some API where Level1 base class can count number of levels it has been derived?

Comment: What's the motivation behind this?

Comment: You should explain the motives to do something like this or else your question might be closed.

Comment: Giant-mega-WTF-codesmell this screams at a screwy design.

Comment: Are you looking for Factory Pattern? This is really weird requirement.. other than you document the last level classes to make them `final`

Comment: Thanks for the response. May be I am completely wrong and it is not possible in java. Just a wild thought that come when I was working with my colleague on one of the design discussions.

Comment: rashid: it's less an issue of "not possible" and more of an issue of why would you want this screwy design? It just smells of bad design as @Matt states above, that you may need to re-think your entire program design.

Comment: +1 for "Giant-meta etc."  Spot on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

introspection api can help you handle that, try something like  :

```
protected Level1() throws RuntimeException {
        if (getClass().equals(Level1.class)) {
            return;
        }

        if (getClass().getSuperclass().equals(Level1.class)) {
            return; // first level or inheritance
        }

        if (getClass().getSuperclass().getSuperclass().equals(Level1.class)) {
            return; // second level or inheritance
        }
        // else
        throw new RuntimeException("Can't implement more than 2 levels");
    }
```

by the way, why do you want to do that ?

Comment: May be this is a wrong design practice. Just a wild thought came in the discussion where we wanted base class (In this case Level1) to be in control of how it gets derived without using conventional java coding methods by making class final or make class constructor private. Thanks for the answer and code solution.

Answer (score 10):

You can use reflection in the constructor and walk the inheritance chain of this.getClass() to see the nesting level. Actually a test for this.getClass().getSuperClass() == Level1.class should do the trick already.

Comment: Yup, this will work very well.  Reflection should be used as a last-resort...but there are very valid cases for using it.

Comment: But what if the derived class implements its constructor without calling `super()`?

Comment: @SJuan76: this is not possible in Java, you always need to call the super constructor, only bytecode tricks can workaround that requirement

Comment: Ok, you are right. I had the idea that since you could explicitly call `super()`, if you didn't then the parent constructor was not called. If there is no `super()` (with or without parameters) in the constructor, then Java adds it.

Answer (score 3):

You can look at the getClass().getSuperclass() etc to check there is not more than N levels to your class.

Its a baffling requirement however. :P

Answer (score 0):

You can make level3 class final then it cannot be extended by any class. A class that is declared final cannot be subclassed.